# remote to windows machine using its built-in Administrator account

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote

I'm working in a company network that under domain control (say `mycompany.com\luke`)
I need to remote to my remote PC at IP `1.2.3.4`, using the builtpin `Administrator` account, After `Win+R` then `mstsc /v 1.2.3.4`, but

1. when I type in `Administrator`, it get to `mycompany.com\Administrator`
2. when I type in `.\Administrator`, it get to `CPPXXXXBBZ\Administrator` (`CPPXXXXBBZ` is my local computer name)

how to do RDP to remote PC using its local Administrator account?

My local PC is Windows 10 1809
My remote PC is Windows server 2016

Note:
I could send and email to IT Dept to ask my remote PC name (it may be something like `SCPXXXXCFC` but I need to fix this because my remote PC (actually VM) got generated automatically, so I can't email everytime I create a new VM

Comment: Windows 10 disables the Built In Administrator account. Use a different Account with Admin Privileges. This is the best approach and keeps the machine secure

Comment: "CPP000393444BBZ\Administrator" - You would need to use the computer name of the remote PC to access the built-in Administrator.  However, you really should verify, if you actually should be using that.  The built-in Administrator is by default disabled.  *Due to your configuration there isn't another way to access the built-in Administrator remotely without the specifying the machine of the username you want to use.*

Comment: Not sure if `mstsc /v 1.2.3.4 /admin` uses local administrator or just tries to connect in a different way. Also nslookup 1.2.3.4 should get you the hostname/computer-name if on same network/DNS-server since you indicated that changes on new VM creation